# Adding a dot after section number in the header with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

When using the spanish option of the babel package, a dot is added after the section number for each section. However, fancyhdr doesn't. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following output:
[image]
As you can see, the dot is missing after the section number in the header. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redefine `\sectionmark` to add the dot, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection. #1}{}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\end{document}
```

[image]